# Memcache vs MySQL in memory

Tags: mysql, database, performance, memcached

I have a database that won't grow much in size. It's current size is about 1 GB.

Achieving the fastest performance is desired.

**Question**:  When should I use Memcache vs simply using MySQL Innodb ability to store all my content within RAM (innodb_buffer_pool_size)?

Answer (score 3):

I would only resort to memcached **if you require more than one server** to hold everything in RAM. Otherwise, you're adding complexity for not much functionality.

Answer (score 1):

mysql is more performance degradated on much threads then memcached. so when you will get much simultaneous requests - memcached will respond almost in the same constant time, but mysql's time will be worse.

anyway - until you get about 3-5k tps (or more) to write - there is no any reasons to make project infrastructure more complex.

Comment: you mean mysql can easily handle 5k transactions per seconds?

Comment: @Ali: nope, I didn't mean *easily*. I meant it is the load mysql is able to handle