# MySQL: Query Cacheing (How do I use memcache?)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an query like:

```
SELECT id as OfferId FROM offers
WHERE concat(partycode, connectioncode) = ? 
AND CURDATE() BETWEEN offer_start_date 
AND offer_end_date AND id IN ("121211, 123341,151512,5145626 ");
```

Now I want to cache the results of this query using memcache and so my question is

1. How can I cache an query using memcache.
2. I am currently using [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/query-cache-operation.html) which cannot be used if we want to implement caching and so how can I get current date functionality without using CURDATE() function ?

Comment: Is this question clear or does it need some more modifications ?

Comment: Is this question basically: How do I use memcache?

Comment: For Memcache look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512571/idiots-guide-to-app-engine-and-memcache and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444011/memcache-vs-mysql-in-memory

Comment: I'm highly sceptical about many of the memcache questions here...people seem to think that memcache is a necessary addition for any [web] application, without any feel for what kinds of data can usefully be put in it. memcache is not a magic fix to make queries faster; with suitable indexes and cache in the database itself, simple queries like this should be fine without it. memcache adds complexity and potentially consistency problems: don't add it to a project until you really need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function getOffers($ids) {
    $key = implode(',', $ids);

    $cache = new Memcache();
    $cache->connect('localhost');
    $content = $cache->get($key);
    if ($content === false) {
        // content is not cached, so we have to run the query
        $content = $yourDb->query('your query here');
        $cache->add($key, $content);
    }

    $cache->close();

    return $content;
}

getOffers(array('121211','123341','151512','5145626'));
```

You can take this a step further by sorting `$ids` so that the same "set" of IDs (but in a different order) will still take advantage of an available cache for that set.

This isn't date-sensitive, but you can make it date sensitive by adding the date string to `$key`